# Apollo Server requires either an existing schema, modules or typeDefs

Tags: server, graphql, nestjs, backend, config

[image]

(node:1576) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Apollo Server requires either an existing schema, modules or typeDefs
at ApolloServer.constructSchema (E:\NestJS\Backup\Intern\internship-api-backend-nestjs\node_modules\apollo-server-express\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\ApolloServer.js:367:19)
at new ApolloServerBase (E:\NestJS\Backup\Intern\internship-api-backend-nestjs\node_modules\apollo-server-express\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\ApolloServer.js:204:72)
at new ApolloServer (E:\NestJS\Backup\Intern\internship-api-backend-nestjs\node_modules\apollo-server-express\dist\ApolloServer.js:60:9)
at GraphQLModule.registerExpress (E:\NestJS\Backup\Intern\internship-api-backend-nestjs\node_modules@nestjs\graphql\dist\graphql.module.js:131:30)
at GraphQLModule. (E:\NestJS\Backup\Intern\internship-api-backend-nestjs\node_modules@nestjs\graphql\dist\graphql.module.js:115:22)    at Generator.next ()
at E:\NestJS\Backup\Intern\internship-api-backend-nestjs\node_modules@nestjs\graphql\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:117:75
at new Promise ()
at Object.__awaiter (E:\NestJS\Backup\Intern\internship-api-backend-nestjs\node_modules@nestjs\graphql\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:16)
at GraphQLModule.registerGqlServer (E:\NestJS\Backup\Intern\internship-api-backend-nestjs\node_modules@nestjs\graphql\dist\graphql.module.js:111:24)
at GraphQLModule. (E:\NestJS\Backup\Intern\internship-api-backend-nestjs\node_modules@nestjs\graphql\dist\graphql.module.js:98:24)
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (E:\NestJS\Backup\Intern\internship-api-backend-nestjs\node_modules@nestjs\graphql\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:62)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1576) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:1576) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.